# php shell interpreter does not recognize a class

Tags: php, shell, command-line, composer-php

I've just installed `psysh`. And I think this is a trivial issue, although I can't find nothing related in Google.

I am trying to instantiate a class that is already mapped in my `composer.json` file with `ps-4` standard.

My `composer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "andrebian/tdd-com-php",
    "description": "Códigos-fonte apresentados no Livro Test-Driven Development, Teste e Design no Mundo Real com PHP",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Andre Cardoso aka andrebian",
            "email": "andrecardosodev@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "CDC\\Loja\\": [
                "src/CDC/Loja",
                "tests/CDC/Loja"
            ],
            "CDC\\Exemplos\\": [
                "src/CDC/Exemplos",
                "tests/CDC/Exemplos"
            ]
        }
    }

}
```

So, I am in project directory. I enter php shell with psysh and try to intantiate a class with

```
>>> $x = new CDC\Exemplos\ConversorDeNumeroRomano
```

But I'm getting error

```
HP Fatal error:  Class 'CDC\Exemplos\ConversorDeNumeroRomano' not found in eval()'d code on line 1
```

Someone can tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Don't know what the deal with `psysh` is, but you need to include the autoload.php file in your vendor folder for your class file to be loaded in automatically.

Comment: Yes, I have `autoload.php` in vendor folder.

Comment: Right? So `require` it.

Comment: Yes, that's what was missing. Thanks @JonStirling.